# TestNG - How to pass variable's value as dataProvider name?

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a string variable `whichSet` that can hold either 3 values "prd", "stg" and "int". In the Test I want to pass the value as dataProvider like this:

```java
@Test(enabled = true, dataProvider = whichSet, dataProviderClass = TestDataProvider.class)
```

But i have the below error:

```
The value for annotation attribute Test.dataProvider must be a constant expression
```

I've already had 3 providers defined as:

```
@DataProvider(name="stg")
@DataProvider(name="prd")
@DataProvider(name="int")
```

Since i'm reading the data provider from another class (not in the test class), so i'm not able to pass the value to that class based on some test condition. Anyway that I can make the `dataProvider = whichSet` work? Thank you

Comment: Annotation cannot accept variable. If you can make `whichSet` constant like `public static final String whichSet = "prd"` can be used in test. But you can't change it.

Comment: oh i see thank you. @PasupathiRajamanickam do you suggest any other ways to pass the env so we can select the data set accordingly? Since we cannot pass that as a param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're trying to add profile to `DataProvider` there should be an external parameter that should drive this. My way of solving this could be by using JVM options.

```
public class Testng {

    @DataProvider(name = "data-provider")
    public Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
        switch(System.getProperty("env")) {
            case "int":
                return new Object[][] { { "int data one" }, { "data two" } };
            case "stg":
                return new Object[][] { { "stage data one" }, { "data two" } };
            case "prod":
                return new Object[][] { { "production data one" }, { "data two" } };
            default:
                return new Object[][] { { "int data one" }, { "data two" } };
        }
    }

    @Test(enabled = true, dataProvider = "data-provider", dataProviderClass = Testng.class)
    public void test(String data) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }

}
```

And run your test using JVM system properties.

**Eclipse:**
[image]

**CLI**

`java -Denv=prod -cp ".:../lib/*" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`